# como puedo obtener dos valore de fecha con jQuery y enviarlos a otro documento?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<input type="text" class="primerFecha" name="">
<input type="text" class="segundaFecha" name="">

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
     <a id="reporteBV" target="_blank">envio</a>
</button>

//aqui quiero enviar las dos fechas

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function(){
    $(".primeraFecha").on("change",function(){
      var valor = $(this).val();
      if (valor >=1){
        $("#reporteBV").attr("href","report/resumenventas.php?fecInicio="+valor);
      }else{
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Debes decirnos cual es tu problema exacto, que es lo que no te da o que error te arroja

Comment: no esque lo que quiero es enviar ambas fechas al documento resumenventas.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes tener en cuenta que cuando utilizas `dropdown-toggle` bootstrap anula los comportamientos por defecto de los elementos, en este caso de la etiqueta `<a>`, entonces lo que podrías hacer es enviar las variables al archivo requerido usando `window.open()`

```js
$(function(){
    $("#btn_envio").click(function(){
        var primerFecha = $(".primerFecha").val();
        var segundaFecha = $(".segundaFecha").val();
      
        if (primerFecha != '' && segundaFecha != ''){
            window.open("report/resumenventas.php?fecInicio=" + primerFecha + "&fecFinal=" + segundaFecha, "_blank")
        }else{
            alert('Faltan campos por llenar');
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="primerFecha" name="">
<input type="text" class="segundaFecha" name="">

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" id="btn_envio">
     <a id="reporteBV" target="_blank" href="#">envio</a>
</button>
```

**Nota:** en el snippet de SOes no funciona `window.open()` pero cuando lo hagas en tu entorno local si te funcionará.

Comment: hola mira con eso puedo recibirlo en otro documento los datos por ejemplo

Comment: $fechas = FacturaData::getBetweenDates($desde, $hasta);

Comment: Eso es parte del back-end tu diste tu ejemplo y redactaste tu pregunta en base a front-end, no entiendo podrías explicarte mejor ?

Comment: esque eso que se envia de las dos fechas las kiero obtener en otro documento y es algo asi   
$fechas = FacturaData::getBetweenDates($_GET["fecInicio"], $_GET["fecFinal"]); en FacturaData::getBetweenDates esta la consulta de la base de datos.

Comment: @alvin enviándolas así como te explico en la respuesta las puedes recibir de la forma en que quieres hacerlo, ya lo intentaste ? Ese archivo PHP va a mostrar algo al usuario o solamente está para procesar datos ? Sí es así deberías usar entonces ajax

Comment: si pero creo tener el problema esque me lo envia de esta forma 02/02/2017 y en la base de datos esta 02-02-2017

Comment: @alvin creo que la base de datos reconoce el formato, si no podrías cambiarlo con funciones de fecha de PHP